# Images aren't moving to next line when resizing window

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div containing some images. I want my images to move to next line when images don't fit within the screen size. But, images just get cut off, they don't break to next line!

html

```
<div class="cd">
        <img src="https://mariongrandvincent.github.io/HTML-Personal-website/img-codePen/slider-logo1.png">
        <img src="https://mariongrandvincent.github.io/HTML-Personal-website/img-codePen/slider-logo1.png">
        <img src="https://mariongrandvincent.github.io/HTML-Personal-website/img-codePen/slider-logo1.png">
        <img src="https://mariongrandvincent.github.io/HTML-Personal-website/img-codePen/slider-logo1.png">
        <img src="https://mariongrandvincent.github.io/HTML-Personal-website/img-codePen/slider-logo1.png">
      </div>
```

css

```
.cd {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.cd img {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 310px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the `flex-wrap` property to `nowrap`. Simply change to `wrap` and flex will take care to take everything to the next row if it does not fit the current one.

```css
.cd {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.cd img {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 310px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cd">
        <img src="https://mariongrandvincent.github.io/HTML-Personal-website/img-codePen/slider-logo1.png">
        <img src="https://mariongrandvincent.github.io/HTML-Personal-website/img-codePen/slider-logo1.png">
        <img src="https://mariongrandvincent.github.io/HTML-Personal-website/img-codePen/slider-logo1.png">
        <img src="https://mariongrandvincent.github.io/HTML-Personal-website/img-codePen/slider-logo1.png">
        <img src="https://mariongrandvincent.github.io/HTML-Personal-website/img-codePen/slider-logo1.png">
      </div>
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :) and don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: Yes of course, I wanted to accept it asap but it says I have to wait for a few mins first, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Change nowrap to wrap in flex-wrap property.
And everything will be fine.